# Completely remove high frequencies from wav file with ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, audio, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, wav

For my speech recognition project, I'd like to completely cut off frequencies above 5000Hz on my wav files using ffmpeg.
I understand there is a lowpass filter for reducing frequencies above a certain value:

```
ffmpeg -i original.wav -af "lowpass=f=5000" lowpass.wav
```

However when I check the spectogram, it seems like frequencies above 5000 have been reduced, not completely cut off

[Voice sample with 5000Hz filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twvoz.png)

How can I completely cut off frequencies with ffmpeg? Any other software is also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the acrossover filter with a somewhat lower value than the actual cutoff.

`ffmpeg -i original.wav -af "acrossover=4500:order=20th[k][r];[r]anullsink;[k]anull" lowpass.wav`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the correct command:

```
sox input.wav output.wav sinc 7.99999k-5k
```

Comment: isn't the small value should come first i.e. 5k-7.9k?

Comment: @Long No, should use 7.9k-5k.

Comment: @Long 7.9k-5k means to reject corresponding freqs, while 5k-7.9k means to keep corresponding freqs only. (check https://www.cloudacm.com/?p=3132)